# How to backup postgresql database with data from windows or linux system?

Tags: postgresql, backup, pgadmin, openproject

I have installed PostgreSQL in Ubuntu Linux system for OpenProject project management tool.

I searched internet i installed pgadmin tool and i tried to backup.

I could backup, but it backups only the sql query in a file.

I want to backup the whole db example- myproject with all data in it.

Comment: Please take a look at the [backup guides for OpenProject](https://docs.openproject.org/installation-and-operations/operation/backing-up/). If you used the package based installation for OpenProject, it should provide what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following:

Step1/ I set automatic for bash script on ubuntu (use "openproject" user)

```
#!/bin/bash
Date=`date +"%Y_%m_%d_%H%M"`
openproject run backup
mkdir /var/db/openproject/backup/op_$Date
mv /var/db/openproject/backup/*.gz /var/db/openproject/backup/*.pgdump /var/db/openproject/backup/op_$Date
```

Step2/ Use "FreeFileSync" to backup from ubuntu server -> dropbox/local host/....

Hoping userful for you!